# Windows Explorer Folder View Settings - TopViews

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I would like to customize the folder views on my Windows machine.

I found the below registry keys, and I've set their LogicalViewMode value to details, their columnlists, etc.

I had to use psexec because these keys are locked.

However, after making these settings

(1) folders are still not in details view,

(2) typing in the start menu does not start a search.

So, I would like to understand what exactly a 'TopView' is, why is there more than 80 of them and what each of these does, because their name does not really help.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\xxx\TopViews\yyy]
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+
FolderType (xxx)                       TopView (yyy)                          FolderType CanonicalName     TopView Name
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+
{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Generic NoName
{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49} {98d06b52-9607-453d-889c-23ad06eab0d0} Generic.Library              Date modified
{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49} {82ba0782-5b7a-4569-b5d7-ec83085f08cc} Generic.Library              Folder
{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49} {77f0bfb4-6aa3-440b-9f6d-1c147467806d} Generic.Library              Name
{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49} {9e2efaeb-e3eb-40a6-a7c1-501242f9b243} Generic.Library              Tag
{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49} {92d203dc-8565-4902-b92c-eaaa54d7364a} Generic.Library              Type
{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} Generic.SearchResults        Date modified
{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943} {bdbe736f-34f5-4829-abe8-b550e65146c4} Generic.SearchResults        Top results
{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Documents                    NoName
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9} {9b371a56-c568-4c17-a8ca-ed0422c8bd20} Documents.Library            Author
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9} {c274421b-f691-4c1f-ae01-a21b4e8a9995} Documents.Library            Date modified
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9} {82ba0782-5b7a-4569-b5d7-ec83085f08cc} Documents.Library            Folder
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9} {fd7f4ad8-a3d9-4073-bf95-18261841333e} Documents.Library            Name
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9} {a34fce31-1399-42a7-b445-2a27e88f85f8} Documents.Library            Tag
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9} {15a6ae7b-c972-47b3-a24a-06e592a3a2a5} Documents.Library            Type
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} {bd6ab8cf-c0fd-4d50-bc73-7aad9b067958} Documents.SearchResults      Author
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} Documents.SearchResults      Date modified
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} {724cded7-242e-425c-b660-86af28ba1567} Documents.SearchResults      Tag
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} {424c81ab-7a7b-4fc1-a848-ddbadc10cdf5} Documents.SearchResults      Top results
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} {bb69f21e-3e71-466e-b8ec-db1a35410985} Documents.SearchResults      Type
{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Pictures                     NoName
{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5} {b7e74fd5-0a6a-476a-9da6-6009c74adf8d} Pictures.Library             Day
{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5} {82ba0782-5b7a-4569-b5d7-ec83085f08cc} Pictures.Library             Folder
{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5} {e5e2e7f6-7a4b-45ce-8b40-9a8e3dd8b9a7} Pictures.Library             Month
{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5} {a186c41c-a75c-44fb-aef2-77a36e0ec1b3} Pictures.Library             Rating
{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5} {c68292a3-bfe0-40d4-82d9-327a5d156771} Pictures.Library             Tag
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} Pictures.SearchResults       Date modified
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} {b79ae9f3-596f-4ba5-9d03-6d13a5a93244} Pictures.SearchResults       Day
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} {e75274f4-6fad-4b24-85b4-c88ccb4a9fbf} Pictures.SearchResults       Month
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} {6c8be494-3282-45a9-8459-bc99b5aadf56} Pictures.SearchResults       Rating
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} {7bd50379-9e59-4230-8a79-d1f0570d159b} Pictures.SearchResults       Tag
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} {5586158e-f4e6-409e-b47c-4d216f40b912} Pictures.SearchResults       Top results
{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Music                        NoName
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b} {3fa62bd1-b86d-4b21-9931-02086472c3e6} Music.Library                Album
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b} {5a07ae71-b138-4e2b-a3d8-815b2ee774e6} Music.Library                Artist
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b} {82ba0782-5b7a-4569-b5d7-ec83085f08cc} Music.Library                Folder
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b} {7c4b404e-47ef-4dcd-aee2-3a8cc3f7a493} Music.Library                Genre
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b} {e4823db9-b055-42e1-a218-3b18fd1b24cb} Music.Library                Rating
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b} {d34ade43-45bd-44ae-84b7-3bcc998826e2} Music.Library                Song
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} {bd6ab8cf-c0fd-4d50-bc73-7aad9b067958} Music.SearchResults          Album
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} {9df9986a-7b7b-4fb1-bdc1-e333f6eeda55} Music.SearchResults          Artist
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} Music.SearchResults          Date modified
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} {1c655225-b392-4f85-b10e-961228212744} Music.SearchResults          Genre
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} {86b0cc03-4a60-4705-849d-b6f6768e436f} Music.SearchResults          Rating
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} {05b0d151-f1bd-4fcc-a591-c37a4f36755c} Music.SearchResults          Song
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} {0167146e-5395-4c48-9048-d584eeaca4f2} Music.SearchResults          Top results
{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Videos                       NoName
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed} {82ba0782-5b7a-4569-b5d7-ec83085f08cc} Videos.Library               Folder
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed} {62c0c838-9084-440e-a64e-acb34d6e9c82} Videos.Library               Length
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed} {83059b98-14a1-4d85-8edb-c46d915ace5a} Videos.Library               Name
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed} {2c0bc161-7181-49ba-8337-10584d53d8d0} Videos.Library               Type
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed} {34cbc45c-eb17-448d-ac3a-838eb3ecdcd0} Videos.Library               Year
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} Videos.SearchResults         Date modified
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} {d684a962-4c84-474e-aa0b-dfd735baabbe} Videos.SearchResults         Length
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} {dfbd6ba3-1846-438f-8675-b65a6bd9d418} Videos.SearchResults         Name
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} {1295023a-b086-4a37-97cc-6cc75e80e020} Videos.SearchResults         Top results
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} {669904a2-83a9-431f-9a21-8d5d9a0bfec9} Videos.SearchResults         Type
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} {2f67e023-315f-47c6-bb85-6fd4d36f21f8} Videos.SearchResults         Year
{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156} {82373c7e-af88-4d88-a330-a310a3d543ca} Communications.SearchResults Top results
{de2b70ec-9bf7-4a93-bd3d-243f7881d492} {ac898246-2808-43c6-892a-0c752c7a99f1} Contacts                     NoName
{524ddb2b-2a4f-43b8-b8fe-e91ef9d8ba69} {68cea772-8984-4605-86b1-3ce41e03162c} Contacts.Library             Category
{524ddb2b-2a4f-43b8-b8fe-e91ef9d8ba69} {0521fd96-0138-4e29-bf27-d7f0881560d5} Contacts.Library             Folder
{524ddb2b-2a4f-43b8-b8fe-e91ef9d8ba69} {69d0dcc8-6e03-44bc-aafb-7e41dbf8aec4} Contacts.Library             Name
{654a1b99-8a4b-4e7b-a4e1-46378ad77a61} {0521fd96-0138-4e29-bf27-d7f0881560d5} Contacts.LibraryFolder       -
{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec} {bad35059-92c4-486c-9c54-dcd37fc26a65} Contacts.SearchResults       Category
{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec} {9ef125c2-d179-4d37-b37d-3c52e4735abf} Contacts.SearchResults       Folder
{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec} {09ae3eb1-f5b3-4852-afc2-37d0a8ac6a1d} Contacts.SearchResults       Name
{8faf9629-1980-46ff-8023-9dceab9c3ee3} {ba8a11b9-75b2-46d2-99db-058e9d780758} OpenSearch                   Top results
{B337FD00-9DD5-4635-A6D4-DA33FD102B7A} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} OtherUsers                   NoName
{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} OtherUsers.SearchResults     Date modified
{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55} {C0868EF8-40A5-46b6-85DD-94CD8F1E5C4A} OtherUsers.SearchResults     Top results
{7F2F5B96-FF74-41da-AFD8-1C78A5F3AEA2} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} PublishedItems               NoName
{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010} {BFD2FA1A-D86A-400e-ACEC-BD81C4595BEB} PublishedItems.SearchResults Date modified
{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010} {9CB07032-B44E-4197-B2DE-034E5B002067} PublishedItems.SearchResults Top results
{982725ee-6f47-479e-b447-812bfa7d2e8f} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} SearchConnector              Date modified
{982725ee-6f47-479e-b447-812bfa7d2e8f} {38ba94a3-127b-4236-b9dc-a2440b9b92b8} SearchConnector              Name
{982725ee-6f47-479e-b447-812bfa7d2e8f} {bdbe736f-34f5-4829-abe8-b550e65146c4} SearchConnector              Top results
{0b0ba2e3-405f-415e-a6ee-cad625207853} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Searches                     NoName
{834d8a44-0974-4ed6-866e-f203d80b3810} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} SearchHome                   NoName
{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} StartMenu                    NoName
{CD0FC69B-71E2-46e5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} UserFiles                    NoName
{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} UserFiles.SearchResults      Date modified
{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b} {85243de1-37fb-482a-a7b6-b6bdea33c6b8} UserFiles.SearchResults      Top results
{C4D98F09-6124-4fe0-9942-826416082DA9} {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} UsersLibraries               NoName
{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D} {4804caf0-de08-42ec-b811-52350e94c01e} UsersLibraries.SearchResults Date modified
{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D} {60EF4631-B67D-4096-99B4-81C72724B8FF} UsersLibraries.SearchResults Top results
{da3f6866-35fe-4229-821a-26553a67fc18} -                                      Generic.LibraryFolder        -
{3f98a740-839c-4af7-8c36-5badfb33d5fd} -                                      Documents.LibraryFolder      -
{c1f8339f-f312-4c97-b1c6-ecdf5910c5c0} -                                      Pictures.LibraryFolder       -
{978e0ed7-92d6-4cec-9b59-3135b9c49ccf} -                                      Music.LibraryFolder          -
{292108be-88ab-4f33-9a26-7748e62e37ad} -                                      Videos.LibraryFolder         -
{91475fe5-586b-4eba-8d75-d17434b8cdf6} -                                      Communications               -
{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9} -                                      CompressedFolder             -
{0c3794f3-b545-43aa-a329-c37430c58d2a} -                                      ControlPanelAllItems         -
{de4f0660-fa10-4b8f-a494-068b20b22307} -                                      ControlPanelCategory         -
{b689b0d0-76d3-4cbb-87f7-585d0e0ce070} -                                      Games                        -
{549461d3-eb58-4c80-ba29-f1204c4502c3} -                                      Internet                     -
{2c7bbec6-c844-4a0a-91fa-cef6f59cfda1} -                                      Printers                     -
{d674391b-52d9-4e07-834e-67c98610f39d} -                                      Programs                     -
{6ef8b050-8a6a-4d79-8344-9dfb5cf391fb} -                                      RestrictedNonIndexed         -
{6D9969FF-612F-48EF-9B90-853FD82E6EC2} -                                      Sync                         -
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: `I had to use psexec because these keys are locked.` .. no, they aren't but you must run the registry editor as an admin.. or whatever program you are using to access these keys.. they are HKLM and require admin privs to modify (but not view).  psexec is for running programs on REMOTE machines.. is this machine REMOTE?  The topviews are there to provide a default set of columns in details mode depending on the folder purpose.  For instance, music might have props like "artist" where this makes no sense for your downloads folder.

Comment: No, you can't edit them with admin privileges, only as System, I read that elsewhere, and also tried it. psexec is not only for remote machines but also for System privilege. What I don't understand about TopViews is why there are so many of them. E.g. for music there are more than 10. I don't see which one is used when.

Comment: I just edited them using regedit without making any permission changes on two different machines.. and yes.. I know that psexec can be used to use certain permissions .. but that's not your point. ;)  .. After looking deeper.. I TOO am baffled at the ludicrous amount of entries.  Sorry I can't help.

Comment: If you just use explorer it will learn what you want. Seeing you don't understand that delete whatever you did, go to *Folder Options* and choose*Reset Folders*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a Library & right-click in the *background* of the folder pane, You will see the option `Arrange by >` in the context menu. Those are the multiple TopViews you see for Libraries. If you execute a search from a Library, you have the same opton in the SearchResults window, and those are the multiple TopViews you see under the SearchResults FolderTypes.

The views defined here are only used if the folder doesn't have a previously saved view and if no user-defined default for the *FolderType* has been created via `Apply to Folders`. So the most likely reason you didn't see your mods is one of those two reasons.

To clear saved views, delete the following two registry keys:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

and to clear custom defaults set by `Applly to Folders`, delete this key:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults
```

A safer way to experiment with FolderTypes & TopViews is to copy the FolderTypes key to `HKCU`. If you create those values, they over-ride the HKLM equivalents for the vast majority of the FolderTypes -- then you don't have the ownership/permission issues you encountered. Easist way to copy the key is:

1. Export to `.reg` file
2. Search & Replace: `HKLM` -> `HKCU`
3. Save & merge

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to "customize the folder views on my Windows machine", you can do it all manually, as you have started to do, or take advantage of the hundreds of hours of work I have put into creating a tool to do just that. Search for WinSetView on GitHub. It will do what you're requesting.